# php, data from object

Tags: php

how get information from Object?

```
$cars = new Cars($car_color, $car_id, $car_speed); 
CAR_class::cars($cars, $car_speed);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the relation between your question and its title?

Comment: *(reference)* [PHP Manual on Classes and Objects](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) is a winrar. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just mean to access the $cars object's variables...

You should have some sort of getter function within your Car class that returns the object's variables. for instance:

```
public function getColor() {

     return $this->color;
}
```

Then you would call the function using something like:

```
$cars->getColor();
```